# How to get the latest version of code from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

So basically this is a pretty "nooby" question but how would I get the latest version of my code from a GitHub repo? In my case, I code on both PC and Mac but I'd like to work on a project on both machines. For example, say if I started a project on PC, coded something and pushed it onto GitHub, then cloned that GitHub repo onto my Mac and coded some more and pushed that code to Github. How would I now update the code on my PC to match the code in the GitHub repo and vice-versa? Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to know the latest commits that have been done on that repo you should go for

```
git log --all --oneline
```

This will list in chronological order all the commits of the repo starting from the most recent one. Instead if you want to look for a stable version of the code you should probably do

```
git pull origin master
```

where by convention *usually* you can find the latest stable version. Beware that this may not be true everywhere and people is not obliged to follow this convention.

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
git pull origin master
```

If your default branch is different than master, you will need to specify branch name :

```
git pull origin default_branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the code on my PC to match the code in the GitHub repo use

`$ git pull origin <branch_name>`  if you want to update specific branch

and run the same command on your Mac to get the changes that you updated to Github

by using

```
$ git log
```

which shows the commit id and other details, by matching the head commit in both local and remote you can verify that you cloned the latest sources